# Using closest() to only show content of clicked title

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html

```
<article class="one_post">
<section class="single_post">
<section class="the_post_title"><h3 data-toggled="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h3></section>
    <section class="the_post_teaser"><p>Teaser Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non magna eu leo placerat accumsan. Maecenas cursus augue id tincidunt sagittis. Duis mattis massa sit amet ipsum laoreet, et elementum felis vulputate. Nam convallis nibh elit, ac consequat diam faucibus a. Praesent ac hendrerit mauris. Donec felis nunc, mattis a scelerisque id, euismod ut neque. Sed lobortis cursus scelerisque.</p></section>
</section>
    <section class="entire_blog_post">
    <article class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</article>
    <article class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non magna eu leo placerat accumsan. Maecenas cursus augue id tincidunt sagittis. Duis mattis massa sit amet ipsum laoreet, et elementum felis vulputate. Nam convallis nibh elit, ac consequat diam faucibus a. Praesent ac hendrerit mauris. Donec felis nunc, mattis a scelerisque id, euismod ut neque. Sed lobortis cursus scelerisque.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non magna eu leo placerat accumsan. Maecenas cursus augue id tincidunt sagittis. Duis mattis massa sit amet ipsum laoreet, et elementum felis vulputate. Nam convallis nibh elit, ac consequat diam faucibus a. Praesent ac hendrerit mauris. Donec felis nunc, mattis a scelerisque id, euismod ut neque. Sed lobortis cursus scelerisque.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non magna eu leo placerat accumsan. Maecenas cursus augue id tincidunt sagittis. Duis mattis massa sit amet ipsum laoreet, et elementum felis vulputate. Nam convallis nibh elit, ac consequat diam faucibus a. Praesent ac hendrerit mauris. Donec felis nunc, mattis a scelerisque id, euismod ut neque. Sed lobortis cursus scelerisque.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non magna eu leo placerat accumsan. Maecenas cursus augue id tincidunt sagittis. Duis mattis massa sit amet ipsum laoreet, et elementum felis vulputate. Nam convallis nibh elit, ac consequat diam faucibus a. Praesent ac hendrerit mauris. Donec felis nunc, mattis a scelerisque id, euismod ut neque. Sed lobortis cursus scelerisque.
</article>
    <section class="col-sm-12 les_green about_the_author">
    <article class="blog_about_the_author"><h3>About The Author</h3></article>
    <article class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non magna eu leo placerat accumsan. Maecenas cursus augue id tincidunt sagittis. Duis mattis massa sit amet ipsum laoreet, et elementum felis vulputate. </article>
    </section>
    <section class="les_comments">
    <article class="les_grey col-sm-12 ">20 comments</article>
    <article class="all_comments">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non magna eu leo placerat accumsan. Maecenas cursus augue id tincidunt sagittis. Duis mattis massa sit amet ipsum laoreet, et elementum felis vulputate. Nam convallis nibh elit, ac consequat diam faucibus a. Praesent ac hendrerit mauris. Donec felis nunc, mattis a scelerisque id, euismod ut neque. Sed lobortis cursus scelerisque.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non magna eu leo placerat accumsan. Maecenas cursus augue id tincidunt sagittis. Duis mattis massa sit amet ipsum laoreet, et elementum felis vulputate. Nam convallis nibh elit, ac consequat diam faucibus a. Praesent ac hendrerit mauris. Donec felis nunc, mattis a scelerisque id, euismod ut neque. Sed lobortis cursus scelerisque.
    </article>
    </section>
    <section class="the_footer">
    </section>
    </section>
    </article>
```

which is a single blog post.I am only showing the post title and upon clicking the content belonging to the displayed title is being displayed.

This is the jquery i am using

```
$('.entire_blog_post').css('display','none');
$('.the_post_title').on('click', function(){
    if (!$(this).attr('data-toggled') || $(this).attr('data-toggled') == 'off'){

           $(this).attr('data-toggled','on');
           $('.the_post_teaser').css('display','none');
$('.entire_blog_post').css('display','');
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('data-toggled') == 'on'){
           $(this).attr('data-toggled','off');
           $('.the_post_teaser').css('display','');
$('.entire_blog_post').css('display','none');
    }
});
```

and this is the result http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/DdjGL/8/

I am trying out

```
$(this).closest('.entire_blog_post').css('display','');
```

but even that doesn't work  http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/A4REL/1/

How can i fix this?.

Comment: Have you tried just by using the .toggle() function in your click statement? See http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just use the .closest() because the elements you are targeting are not the ancestor elements, they are in a sibling element

```
$('.entire_blog_post').css('display', 'none');
$('.the_post_title').on('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).attr('data-toggled') || $(this).attr('data-toggled') == 'off') {

        $(this).attr('data-toggled', 'on');
        $(this).siblings('.the_post_teaser').hide();
        $(this).closest('.single_post').next('.entire_blog_post').show();
    } else if ($(this).attr('data-toggled') == 'on') {
        $(this).attr('data-toggled', 'off');
        $(this).siblings('.the_post_teaser').show();
        $(this).closest('.single_post').next('.entire_blog_post').hide();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kaaLP/)

It can be much more simplified to

```
$('.entire_blog_post').hide();
$('.the_post_title').on('click', function () {
    //the teaser is the next element of the tile
    $(this).next('.the_post_teaser').toggle();
    //entire_blog_post is the next sibling of the ancestor single_post element
    $(this).closest('.single_post').next('.entire_blog_post').toggle();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qa4V4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.entire_blog_post').css('display', 'none');
$('.the_post_title').on('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).attr('data-toggled') || $(this).attr('data-toggled') == 'off') {

        $(this).attr('data-toggled', 'on');
        $(this).parent().find('.the_post_teaser').css('display', 'none');
        $(this).closest('.entire_blog_post').css('display', '');
    } else if ($(this).attr('data-toggled') == 'on') {
        $(this).attr('data-toggled', 'off');
        $('.the_post_teaser').css('display', '');
        $('.entire_blog_post').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/A4REL/2/)

OR:

```
$('.the_post_title').on('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).attr('data-toggled') || $(this).attr('data-toggled') == 'off') {

        $(this).attr('data-toggled', 'on');
    } else if ($(this).attr('data-toggled') == 'on') {
        $(this).attr('data-toggled', 'off');
    }
    $(this).parent().find('.the_post_teaser').slideToggle();
    $(this).closest('.entire_blog_post').slideToggle();
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/A4REL/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a class to define if it is hidden or not like this:

```
.the_post_teaser{
display:none;
}

.entire_blog_post{
display:block;
}

.is-hidden .the_post_teaser {
display:block;
}

.is-hidden .entire_blog_post {
display:none;
}
```

Then you can just toggle the class:

`$(this).closest('.entire_blog_post').toggleClass('is-hidden');`

OR

Just use an already present selector to hide it:

```
[data-toggled='on'] .entire_blog_post {
display:none;
}

[data-toggled='off'] .the_post_teaser {
display:none;
}
```